# How to include JS lib in my Angular 2 project?

Tags: angularjs, angular, import, tween

I managed to instal Tween js `npm install tween` but  i can't import it to my component ?

My lib is install in node_modules/tween.

I tried :

```
import * AS TWEEN from 'tween/tween.js'
import {TWEEN} from 'tween'
```

But it's not working.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best way, but the way I do this sometimes:

Include the script in your index.html file:

```
<head>
   ...
   <script src="path/to/script"></script>
   ...
</head>
```

Access the script through window object:

```
window.SCRIPTNAME
```

Example with screenfull.js:

```
<script src="/assets/scripts/screenfull.min.js"></script>
```

I access it like this in my code:

```
window.screenfull
```

Comment: The main problem is i don't have access to an index.html, i use ionic2 and this file seems to be created after compilation.

Answer (score 1):

I'have been struggling with the similar problem from two days. Here is what I got.

```
npm install @types/tween.js --save
npm install tween.js --save-dev
```

The package name after the @types/ must be the same as the second one. I was stupid installed `npm install tween --save-dev` instead of `tween.js` before, and I had no idea what was wrong, wasted hours to figuer this out.
And in your *tsconfig.json* add

```
"compilerOptions":{..."types":[..."tween.js"]}
```

then you can

```
import * as TWEEN from "tween.js"
```

Hope this could help.